# Proving size of Binary Search Tree in Dafny

Tags: dafny

I am trying to prove the correctness of a binary search tree implementation in Dafny, but I am struggling to prove that the computed size corresponds to the size of the elements set.

So far I have written the following code:

```
datatype TreeSet =
   Leaf
 | Node(left: TreeSet, data: int, right: TreeSet)

predicate Valid(treeSet: TreeSet) {
    match treeSet
        case Leaf => true
        case Node(left, data, right) => Valid(left) && Valid(right)
            && treeSet != left && treeSet != right
            && (forall elem :: elem in elems(left) ==> elem < data)
            && (forall elem :: elem in elems(right) ==> elem > data)
            && treeSet !in descendants(left)
            && treeSet !in descendants(right)
}

function descendants(treeSet: TreeSet) : set<TreeSet> {
    match treeSet {
        case Leaf => {}
        case Node(left, _, right) => descendants(left) + descendants(right)
    }
}

function size(treeSet: TreeSet): nat
requires Valid(treeSet)
ensures |elems(treeSet)| == size(treeSet)
{
  match treeSet
    case Leaf => 0
    case Node(left,_,right) =>
      size(left) + 1 + size(right)
}

function elems(treeSet: TreeSet): set<int>
{
    match treeSet
        case Leaf => {}
        case Node(left, data, right) => elems(left) + {data} + elems(right)
}
```

Dafny is failing to prove the `size` function, specifically the `ensures |elems(treeSet)| == size(treeSet)` postcondition.

It can infer that the cardinality of the element set is lesser than or equal to the size function, but not that it is equal. I tried to assert both the tree invariant the uniqueness of elements in the `Valid` predicate, but it still cannot prove the correctness of the function. Any idea of how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this post condition by adding an inline assertion like this:

```
function size(treeSet: TreeSet): nat
requires Valid(treeSet)
ensures |elems(treeSet)| == size(treeSet)
{
  match treeSet
    case Leaf => 0
    case Node(left,x,right) =>
      assert forall elem :: !(elem in elems(left) && elem in elems(right));  // NEW
      size(left) + 1 + size(right)
}
```

Couple other notes:

- I think something is weird with your `descendants` function: it always returns the empty set!
- In `Valid`, you don't need the clauses `treeSet != left` or `treeSet != right`, those are "obvious" to Dafny based on the datatype declaration. You probably also don't need `treeSet !in descendants(left)` or `treeSet !in descendants(right)` even though they are not so obvious.

Comment: Regarding the other wonkiness in the file, I assumed there could be referencial cycles, but from further reading of the language reference manual, I am now convinced that inductive types will not really suffer from it.

Comment: Right, datatypes don't have cycles in Dafny, even though other parts of Dafny can have cycles.